# Strange issues with webcam + Linux + VMWare

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware, webcam

I have a server machine hosting a Linux VM using VMWare vSphere 6.0. I am trying to get a webcam to work with it. However, I've been having two main issues:

1. The frame rate is extremely low (0.1fps - 1.0fps).
2. The output image has several glitches (as seen in the examples below).

I tried to install multiple Linux distributions (i.e. CentOS, Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04, Mint 18.1), and the results are the same. I also tried with two different webcams: Microsoft LifeCam Cinema HD and a generic one (Sunplus Technology). Both cameras work fine on a physical machine running Mint and Ubuntu.

However, both cameras also work just fine on a Windows 10 running on a Virtual Machine at the same server.

To give some technical details, the following message gets printed very frequently when I run `guvcview` on Linux:

```
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporary unavailable.
```

I also captured 2 images using `guvcview` to show how the image quality is. One of them was using MJPG:

[image: MJPG]

and the other one with RGB3:

[image: RGB3]

The remaining "camera output" options had poor quality results as well. Additionally, as you can see at the top bar, the frame rate is very low.

It is important to note that I also tried to capture the frame using multiple methods besides `guvcview`, such as `streamer`, `webcam` and OpenCV.

Would anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: For something that specific I'd pass through a PCI to USB card to that VM. I'm assuming you are just attaching the webcam via USB to the VM.

Comment: The problem is with vmware messing with USB. It has nothing to so with Linux or your camera.